# If ngDoCheck is used for simple assignments, is it still inefficient?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am checking if a url has changed or not using ngDoCheck. This is composed of a simple `if statement` and just assigning properties. No for loops and I would consider the big O to be constant. Please take a look at my code.

```js
ngDoCheck() {
  if (this.router.url === '/recipes') {
    this.recipeService.falseClickedOnStatus()
  }
  else {
    this.recipeService.trueClickedOnStatus()
  }
  this.clickedOn = this.recipeService.clickedOn
 }
```

Again, this is simply checking if the router changed or not and I am just assigning values. However, since ngDoCheck is run **A LOT**, can this particular code snippet cause memory leaks? Or since I am using it for a simple case, it won't

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The point is, that it is not running "a lot" is running whenever ChangeDetection finds anything. And depending on how `this.clickedOn` is used, this operation could retrigger change detection in itself